# Printing session multiple value of a checkbox array in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I am creating a website for multiple products which have 4 properties front, back, side and addon (which is chargeable), created a simple demo below is the code.

PROPERTIES PAGE(prop.php)

```
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
        <body>
            YOU HAVE CHOOSED <h1>PRODUCT 1</h1>

       <h2>CHOOSE PRODUCT PROPERTIES</h2>
            <form action="cartpage.php" method="post">
                ORDER ID <input type="text" id="uid" name="oid" value="<?php echo uniqid(); ?>"><br><br>
                <label>FRONT SELECTION</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="front_sel" value="front_1">FRONT 1<br>
                <input type="radio" name="front_sel" value="front_2">FRONT 2<br>
                <input type="radio" name="front_sel" value="front_3">FRONT 3<br>
                <input type="radio" name="front_sel" value="front_4">FRONT 4<br><br>
                <label>BACK SELECTION</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="back_sel" value="back_1">BACK 1<br>
                <input type="radio" name="back_sel" value="back_2">BACK 2<br>
                <input type="radio" name="back_sel" value="back_3">BACK 3<br>
                <input type="radio" name="back_sel" value="back_4">BACK 4<br><br>
                <label>SIDE SELECTION</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="side_sel" value="side_1">SIDE 1<br>
                <input type="radio" name="side_sel" value="side_2">SIDE 2<br>
                <input type="radio" name="side_sel" value="side_3">SIDE 3<br>
                <input type="radio" name="side_sel" value="side_4">SIDE 4<br><br>
                <label>ADD ON SELECTION</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="addon_sel[]" value="addon_1">THIS ADDON COST Rs 50 EXTRA<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="addon_sel[]" value="addon_2">THIS ADDON COST Rs 20 EXTRA<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="addon_sel[]" value="addon_3">THIS ADDON COST Rs 0 EXTRA<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="addon_sel[]" value="addon_4">THIS ADDON COST Rs 10 EXTRA<br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

php cart page (cartpage.php)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $oid = $_POST['oid'];
    $front = $_POST['front_sel'];
    $back = $_POST['back_sel'];
    $side = $_POST['side_sel'];
    $addon = $_POST['addon_sel'];
    $cart = array (
    'front' => $front,
    'back' => $back,
    'addon' => $addon,
    'side' => $side 
    );

    $_SESSION['oid'] = $oid;
    $_SESSION['cart'][$oid] = $cart;
    echo "ITEMS IN YOUR CART<br>";
     foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) {
         echo $item['front']."<br>";
         echo $item['back']."<br>";
         echo $item['side']."<br>";
         echo $item['addon']."<br>";
         if ($item['addon'] == 'addon_1')
         {
             echo "TOTAL PRICE OF THE PRODUCT IS Rs. 500 + Price of ADDON Rs 50 = Rs. 550/-" ;
         }if ($item['addon'] == 'addon_2')
         {
             echo "TOTAL PRICE OF THE PRODUCT IS Rs. 500 + Price of ADDON Rs 20 = Rs. 520/-" ;
         }if ($item['addon'] == 'addon_3')
         {
             echo "TOTAL PRICE OF THE PRODUCT IS Rs. 500 + Price of ADDON Rs 0 = Rs. 500/-" ;
         }if ($item['addon'] == 'addon_1')
         {
             echo "TOTAL PRICE OF THE PRODUCT IS Rs. 500 + Price of ADDON Rs 10 = Rs. 510/-" ;
         }
     }
}
?>
```

**First :**
In the above code whenever user checks on multiple checkboxes it takes only post one checkbox.

**Second**
I want multiple checkboxes in the session for creating a cart system and appointing price to them.
Hope you understand the problem  Please help me and please tell me any other way for doing the same. Thanks.

Comment: If you really want to avoid square brackets, then ask if checkboxes were posted: `if(isset($_POST['addon_sel_1']))` , `if(isset($_POST['addon_sel_2']))` , and so on, assuming checkboxes don't have `[]` but unique names. Then you do `$_SESSION['addon1']=$_POST['addon_sel_1']`.

Answer (score 0):

Your checkboxes all have the same `name="addon_sel"`. PHP's default behavior for multiple fields with the same name is to save only the LAST encountered value. Use `name="addon_sel[]"` (note the `[]`) to tell PHP to create an array of values received.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I have added the [] but not satisfy my expectation, actually, I want ids of all checkboxes so than I can assign them correct price according to that.

Comment: checkboxes which are not checked by the user will NOT be submitted.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I have added the [] brackets, I just want the way to get the each id of addon what user have selected.

Comment: Yes I want ids of each checkbox what user checked and save it in session like all other variables

Comment: Yes that will be as an array or any other method which you may know will be better than this .

Comment: I am not getting multiple selections, please guide for the same. how will i access each checked checkboxes?

Comment: you really need to start learning how to debug your own code. `$_POST['addon_sel']` is going to be an ARRAY. you're comparing that array against values, which will never work. `$item['addon'] == 'addon_1'` will always return false.

Comment: Is there any other way to solve my problem, please help

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in your code to make it work, those changes are pointed by arrows (`//<=================`) :

```
<?php
session_start();                           //<=================
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $oid = $_POST['oid'];
    $front = $_POST['front_sel'];
    $back = $_POST['back_sel'];
    $side = $_POST['side_sel'];
    $addon = $_POST['addon_sel'];         // ADDONS ARRAY.
    $cart = array ( 'front' => $front,
                    'back' => $back,
                    'addon' => $addon,
                    'side' => $side 
                  );
    $_SESSION['oid'] = $oid;
    $_SESSION['cart'][$oid] = $cart;
    echo "ITEMS IN YOUR CART<br>";
     foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) {
         echo $item['front']."<br>";
         echo $item['back']."<br>";
         echo $item['side']."<br>";
         print_r( $item['addon'] )."<br>";     //<=================
         if ( in_array( 'addon_1',$item['addon'] ) ) //<=================
         {
             echo "<br/>TOTAL PRICE OF THE PRODUCT IS Rs. 500 + Price of ADDON Rs 50 = Rs. 550/-" ;
         }if ( in_array( 'addon_2',$item['addon'] ) ) //<=================
         {
             echo "<br/>TOTAL PRICE OF THE PRODUCT IS Rs. 500 + Price of ADDON Rs 20 = Rs. 520/-" ;
         }if ( in_array( 'addon_3',$item['addon'] ) ) //<=================
         {
             echo "<br/>TOTAL PRICE OF THE PRODUCT IS Rs. 500 + Price of ADDON Rs 0 = Rs. 500/-" ;
         }if ( in_array( 'addon_4',$item['addon'] ) ) //<=================
         {
             echo "<br/>TOTAL PRICE OF THE PRODUCT IS Rs. 500 + Price of ADDON Rs 10 = Rs. 510/-" ;
         }
     }
}
?>
```